# Apache redirect http to https too many redirects errors

Tags: apache, https

Here is the rewrite rule generated by certbot.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mysite.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysite.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

It does not work and browser show too many redirects erros.

Comment: Please post the entire virtual host. This is not enough to check what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/$    index.php    [L]
```

use this code which will redirect your domain to http://www.*.*  and avoid to many redirection

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.